# I see "held for review 11" YouTube comments on my page but nothing shows up

Tags: youtube-channel

I have checked and rechecked all settings.  I do have checked in the box to allow all comments when I upload a videos.  However lately I watched a video I posted and saw it say underneath the video, comments waiting for approval.  So, I clicked on it and shows "held for review 11". But it **doesn't show any comments**. I'm so confused as to why?  It did that before and I was able to view the comments and decide if I thought it was spam or not.  Now I can't see nothing at all except 11 next to held for review.  I checked other videos and does the same except next to held for review is different numbers, some say held for review 2 or held for review 6.  What is weird is people that have already commented on my videos still can. Can someone please help me out with this problem.

Comment: can you link such video?

Comment: now it also says likely spam 6 also, however as it did that a few times I was still able to view all comments then decide if I thought it was spam or not.  I don't see no comments what so ever. I see my sub's comments but they are not under review either.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/twH7t.png

Comment: ja! wow. So I see it now. I think. the 6 comments are the 6 comments awaiting for review?  Even though they don't show up on the page when I click the blue REVIEW right after it says you have comments awaiting your review

Comment: on my page shows the 11 comments, however right under comments it says you have comments awaiting your review, I click on the blue REVIEW and nothing shows up.  Because they are already posted? So that's the 11 it is talking about "awaiting"?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXQBL.png

Comment: Well thank you very much if that is the case? Just wasn't doing that before people were posting. And 1 day I logged on and noticed that. So, was so confused, checked settings, checked google on it, checked youtube. And still don't make sense, if they were "awaiting" why would they not show up when I clicked Review? But I'm new to posting vids, so guess that is how it works. THANK YOU so much for the help as this was annoying me so bad! Wish they would atleast show up so I would of known, well ya they are already posted! Thanks again! Means a lot.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/SYhRljp

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/DCqVnqD